# Problems using in_array and date in if/else

Tags: php, arrays, date

I am experimenting with the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [in_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) functions of PHP.

Based on what I have read in the manual I can't understand why my code is returning the else part of the if statement. If the **date('D')** is returning **Tue** why doesn't it run the if part?

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$weekdays = array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");

$today = date('D');

if(in_array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", $weekdays) == $today)
   {
         echo "It's" . " ";
         echo $today;
         echo " " . "Get out of bed and go to work";
    }else{
         echo "Do whatever you want becuase it's" . " ";
         echo $today;
};
?>
```

I've tried various things and and changed the **if** part to this, but to no avail.

```
if(in_array(array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri"), $weekdays) == $today)
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in_array` function [checks if a value exists in an array, returning true or false](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

If you want to know if `$today` is a weekday, you would want to do something like:

```
$weekdays = array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri");
if(in_array($today, $weekdays)) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if(in_array($today, $weekdays))
   {
         echo "It's" . " ";
         echo $today;
         echo " " . "Get out of bed and go to work";
    }else{
         echo "Do whatever you want becuase it's" . " ";
         echo $current_day;
};
```

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) manual